# need help in how to request data to the backend or help in post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, backend, web-frontend

i need assistance in posting and retrieve data from the Backend. Right now the code is for HTML but i need to change the commands to work for the server how i ll change them to fetch and post the data to the server.
The code is just added below to show what changes should i make to work for the backend ..
Just need those

```js
function moveClawDown(){
    grabber_arm.animate({ top: -220 }, 2000, function(){
        // show the prize box
        // check if user has won
    if( win_on == number_of_tries )
            prize.show().css('background-image', 'url(./img/item_1.png)');
        setTimeout(moveClawUp, 250);
    });
 
}

// function to move the claw up
function moveClawUp(){
    grabber_arm.animate({ top: -800 }, 2000, function(){

        // check if user has won
        if( win_on != number_of_tries ){

            grabber_arm.animate({ left: '50%' }, 1000 );
            setTimeout( function(){ restart_btn.show() }, 1000);
            number_of_tries++;
        }
        else{
            // user has won - get random prize
            setTimeout( function(){
                win_box.html("<div class=\"win-message\"><p>YOU'VE WON!</p><img src=\""+products[random_prize][2]+"\"><p>"+products[random_prize][1]+"</p><button>Checkout</button></div>").show();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}

// calculates how far the claw has moved
function calculateDistance(){
    claw_position = grabber_arm.offset().left - grabber_wrapper.offset().left;
    claw_position = Math.round(claw_position);
}

// function for returning a random number
function getRandomNumber(numberRange) {
   return Math.floor(( Math.random() * numberRange ) + 1);
}

// function to add images of prizes in random places
function addPrizes(){
    prizes_wrapper.append("<img class=\"prize\" src=\"img/gift.jpg\" />");
}
```

Comment: You need ajax , take a look at jquery ajax

Comment: read about the fetch api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API it's more simple than the regular ajax

Comment: @AlleoIndong i want to know how to send this data to the backend e.g
`if( win_on == number_of_tries )
            prize.show().css('background-image', 'url(./img/item_1.png)');
        setTimeout(moveClawUp, 250);
    }); `
this is just for html
but if i want to send or retrieve this data how i will do that ?

Comment: is the backend ready and can accept requests? @ArsalanEhsan

Comment: @AlleoIndong yeah backend is ready and yes can accept request

Comment: [here you can check the backend](http://54.223.88.132:4002/docs/#!/default/getGrabber)

Comment: then you will just have to learn the fetch api from mozilla and you are good to go, go and check that link that I gave